# Using a modulus in recursion in Python

Tags: python, modulus

Newbie trying to add the digits of an int with a recursive function in Python. When I debug with a print statement, I can see that my program is calculating all of the digits except for the next-to-last digit. For example, if I pass in the number(12345), the program will calculate 5, then skip 4, and then calculate the remaining digits. This happens with any number of digits. I wonder why the modulus is isolating all the digits except for the next-to-last digit. (The result is also incorrect in other ways but I'd like to focus on how the modulus operates recursively.)

The code is:

```
def sumDigits(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        temp = x % 10
        x = x / 10
        print ('x = ', x, 'temp = ', temp)
        return temp + sumDigits(x -1)
```

The result reads:

```
>>> sumDigits(5678)
('x = ', 567, 'temp = ', 8)
('x = ', 56, 'temp = ', 6)
('x = ', 5, 'temp = ', 5)
('x = ', 0, 'temp = ', 4)
24
>>> sumDigits(3456789)
('x = ', 345678, 'temp = ', 9)
('x = ', 34567, 'temp = ', 7)
('x = ', 3456, 'temp = ', 6)
('x = ', 345, 'temp = ', 5)
('x = ', 34, 'temp = ', 4)
('x = ', 3, 'temp = ', 3)
('x = ', 0, 'temp = ', 2)
37
>>>
```

Thanks very much for any information.

Comment: Please note that I'm not asking for correct code for the problem. I know that exists in many places. I'm asking a specific question about the modulus operator and I've spent hours looking for the answer.

Comment: Not all recursion reduction happens with `- 1`. Here you have ylready your reduction with `/ 10`. `- 1` subtracts one (d'oh!) and thus you lose the value of 1 on all calls but the first.

Comment: I think, your code is not correct. Thats why this is happening

Comment: Thank you @glglgl - that's the key I was missing in solving the problem on a meta level. Please let me know if I can give you credit for that answer.

Comment: @crshmk It was just a minor addition to AerofoilKite's answer, so if you credit him, that's enough.

Comment: @AerofoilKite Hasn't apparent malfunctioning most of the time its cause in wrong code?

Comment: @crshmk BTW, your `print` debugging is nice to start with, but had been more helpful wif you extended it a bit: e. g., with shoung old, new and incoming `x` values in the function. So you see what really happens step by step.

Comment: Thanks, @glglgl I'll try to experiment with that debug statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**12345**, Here **5** comes first time. Then you are passing actually **4-1, 3-1, 2-1, 1-1**

Use

```
return temp + sumDigits(x)
```

instead of

```
return temp + sumDigits(x - 1)
```

You should also change here:

```
def sumDigits(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
```

Otherwise, it will add extra one

Comment: Oh I see - there's not a need to decrement the variable because you're decrementing the len(s), so to speak.

So, there is a different operation performed in the first pass.

Comment: Ok thanks - I know that was a simple question, but now I have enough points to participate in the site. And it was helpful for me. Cheers.

Comment: Also, thanks for the 'return 0' - I needed that too.